# Assigning a Target for UISegmentedControl Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have a `UISegmentedControl` that aims to toggle between 3 types of map views "Standard", ".Hybrid", and "Satellite".  I am getting the following error on the line  ".addTarget" Line.

> "Editor placeholder in source file"

```
    let  segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite"])
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    // EVENT LISTENER FOR SEGMENT CONTROL
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "mapTypeChanged:", for: .valueChanged)

    func mapTypeChanged(segControl: UISegmentedControl){
        switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = .standard
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = .hybrid
        case 2:
            mapView.mapType = .satellite
        default:
            break
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let  segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite"])
segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

// EVENT LISTENER FOR SEGMENT CONTROL
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "mapTypeChanged:", for: .valueChanged)

func mapTypeChanged() //removing the auto complete params
{
    switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = .standard
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = .hybrid
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

pls try with this..

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things happening here. You need to use a **#selector** and change the declaration of your function to suppress the first argument naming, otherwise you would have to declare it also in the selector.

```
    let  segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite"])
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

// EVENT LISTENER FOR SEGMENT CONTROL

segmentedControl.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(mapTypeChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

func mapTypeChanged(_ segControl: UISegmentedControl){

    switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0: mapView.mapType = .standard
    case 1: mapView.mapType = .hybrid
    case 2: mapView.mapType = .satellite
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: "Use of local variable 'mapTypeChanged' before its declaration"

Comment: Where are you inserting this code? Inside a ViewController?

Comment: inside loadView() of UIViewController

Comment: Move it to "viewDidLoad"

Comment: i am creating a MAPView programmatically so should it not be in loadView?\

Comment: No, you use "loadView" if you wanna override the default "view" of the ViewController. What you wanna do, in this case, is create the MAPView on "viewDidLoad" and added it as a subView of the "view".

Comment: I;ve done as you suggested but getting the same error as mentioned just above. on the same line

Comment: CMD + K to clean the workspace and build it again, if it still happens, declare the #selector again to see what the auto-complete tells you.